# rsnapshot backup TO remote server

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

I just bought 100GB of "Cloud"-Space at Strato's HiDrive for remote server backups.
They offer the following services: [sftp,webdav,smb/cifs,rsync,scp](http://www.strato-faq.co.uk/artikel.html?articleid=2301)

Now i want to do a remote backup to my Backup-Space using rsnapshot.
All the examples I found were only for backing up FROM remote servers to local machine, but not for backing up TO remote servers.

How can I do incremental backups using rsnapshot using one of the protocols above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of [Roy Kaldung](https://serverfault.com/a/430777/125240) didn't work because the hardlink creation failed.

The way you CAN do it is by creating a loop filesystem and just mounting and using that.

Answer (score 0):

`rsnapshot` only saves to local file systems.

From the manpage for the parameter `snapshot_root`:

> snapshot_root Local filesystem path to save all snapshots

It might be possible to mount your backup space locally (WebDAV, SMB, or sshfs via fuse), but I am not sure  this would be of much use as I don't know if hardlinks like rsnapshot needs them work on any of these remote file systems. My guess is that it's not working and this is why it insists on local file systems in the first place.

Comment: Even though the remote Server supports rsync, it doesn't work? That seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to mount your HiDrive to a local path and use this as the rsnapshot_root. You can use sshfs (sftp), webdav or cifs to mount the HiDrive.
Consider also the documentation how to use cmd_preexec and cmd_postexec to mount and unmount your HiDrive.

Comment: cmd_preexec gets executed after checking if the backup-directory exists. If the preexec-script fails, it puts the backup onto the completely wrong machine.. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zulakis: I had a similar issue.  I wrote a simple wrapper script for rsnapshot, which mounts the target file system, runs rsnapshot with the passed arguments, and then unmounts.  Instead of running rsnapshot from cron, I run my wrapper script.